# Visual Basic - internet transfer control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How to add to toolbox internet transfer control , i read that

Project menu>Component>...
But in my Project menu dosent exists "Component"

i tried Project>add new item but there is no label components or internet transfer control

Comment: I think you must be following a tutorial/guide for VB 6, not .NET. If you could say which feature(s) you were hoping to use, we could probably point you towards the .NET equivalents.

Comment: i need to use binarydata() = Inet1.OpenURL("url", 1)

Comment: Use an [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) object, once it's set up correctly, call [`GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) and then call [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) on that. That will give you a standard `Stream` to then deal with as you wish.